# How to test a Anonymous controller

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I started writing unit tests using Jasmine for angularJS applications and stuck when writing a unit test to the controller in model which doesn't have a name.

How can I instantiate the controller in the model and test the controller?

```
        angular.module('test',[])
            .controller('alpha', function($scope, $modal){
                $scope.openModal = function() {
                    $modal.open({
                        templateUrl: 'template.html',
                        backdrop: true,
                        windowClass: 'content-modal hbox',
                        controller: function(
                            $scope,
                            $modalInstance
                        ) {
                            $scope.test = function() {
                                //test
                            }    
                        }
                    ));
                }

            });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that a UI Bootstrap modal?

Comment: Looks like a Foundation Angular modal directive - http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/

Comment: @MathewFoscarini yes its a UI Bootstrap Modal.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest it is much easier to unit test if you don't use an anonymous function for your controller. If you just write out another full controller you can use it for your modal and test it easily.

That said - here are several approaches to doing what you want to do: http://sirarsalih.com/tag/unit-testing-anonymous-javascript-functions/

Comment: Thanks @lwalden, that makes sense but the only problem is there are many anonymous controllers in the project with dependencies from other controllers which can't be easily migrated.